# How can I specify that ASP.NET themes should not be applied to a specific folder?

Tags: asp.net, themes

I happen to have an ASP.NET 2.0 project that I want to apply a site-wide theme to.  As such, I've specified the theme in the `web.config` file by setting the "theme" attibute of the system.web.pages element.

Now, I've added a new folder containing third-party code that I do not wish to apply the theme to (in fact, I can't, because many of the third party pages do not have the head `runat="server"` tag as required by the ASP.NET theming system).  Is there a way to specify a folder that should be **excluded** from the theme from within the `web.config` file, without having to alter any of the third-party pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this with a page directive theming =false

alternatively, place a web config file in the folder, this will apply for that folder only.

This should demonstrate for you

http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-apply-different-configuration-settings-in-web-config-to-specific-pages-and-folders-in-asp-net-website.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea (that I have never tried):

maybe it's possible by using a location element in web.config, e.g:

```
<system.web>
    <pages theme="MyTheme">
    ..
</system.web>
<location path="~/3rdPartyPages">
    <system.web>
        <pages theme=""></pages>
    </system.web>
</location>
```